# Does the C# compiler remove an if that encapsulates a debug.writeline

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-optimization

I have a piece of code like this:

```
if (state != "Ok")
{
     Debug.WriteLine($"Error occured: {state}, {moreInfo}");
}
```

Does the compiler optimize this away if i make a release build? Or does the evaluation stay and thus costing some processing time?

Comment: Use the `Debug.WriteLineIf` method.

Comment: Note: There is no single C# compiler.  There are several C# compilers, each of which have been released in many versions.  The C# spec has very few (if any) obligatory optimizations, so your answer could only ever be with respect to a particular compiler and a particular version.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, it does, at least for the `Debug` call. I can't see here if the JIT compiler also removed the evaluation of the `if`, but I guess it does since the equation doesn't have any side effects.

However, you are better of keeping it safe by calling `Debug.WriteLineIf`, which doesn't depend on the JIT compiler to remove the evaluation.

For completeness the proof for the compiler to remove the `Debug.WriteLine`.

---

The code in Release build:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       17 (0x11)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  call       string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
  IL_0005:  ldstr      "Ok"
  IL_000a:  call       bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Inequality(string,
                                                                   string)
  IL_000f:  pop
  IL_0010:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Code in Debug build:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       42 (0x2a)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] string state,
           [1] bool V_1)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  call       string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldloc.0
  IL_0008:  ldstr      "Ok"
  IL_000d:  call       bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Inequality(string,
                                                                   string)
  IL_0012:  stloc.1
  IL_0013:  ldloc.1
  IL_0014:  brfalse.s  IL_0029
  IL_0016:  nop
  IL_0017:  ldstr      "Error occured: {0}"
  IL_001c:  ldloc.0
  IL_001d:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string,
                                                              object)
  IL_0022:  call       void [System]System.Diagnostics.Debug::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0027:  nop
  IL_0028:  nop
  IL_0029:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

As you see the Release mode has no call to `Debug.WriteLine`, where the Debug mode does.

Comment: Is there a way to verify that the JIT does remove it?

Comment: Not as far as I know. It is a black box.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Nice answer.

Comment: i did not know Debug.WriteLineIf. I like it! thanks!

Comment: So where is the proof that JIT removes if, which you _demanded_ ?

Comment: The JIT is indeed a black box, and it doesn't provide any explicit/documented guarantees that it will remove the if statement, but you certainly can verify *empirically* whether it does or not. Run the compiled code under a debugger and look at the disassembly. Make sure to enable JIT optimization when running under the debugger; I can't remember if it's off by default in VS.

Comment: @CodyGray Okay, not too much experience with that to say anything useful about that, but the better option is to use `WriteLineIf`, which I tried to emphasize with the update.

Comment: The Release code still calls `System.String::op_Inequality`.  I'd say it still evaluates the `if` statement, but it's treated like it has an empty body.

Comment: It depends on the JIT compiler which kicks in on runtime @brian

Answer (score 15):

From [MSDN's page on the Debug class:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If you use methods in the `Debug` class to print debugging information and check your logic with assertions, you can make your code more robust without impacting the performance and code size of your shipping product.
>
> ...
>
> The `ConditionalAttribute` attribute is applied to the methods of `Debug`. Compilers that support `ConditionalAttribute` ignore calls to these methods unless "DEBUG" is defined as a conditional compilation symbol.

As you can see, the compiler will omit any calls to `Debug` members on non-debug builds. However, it will not stop the program from checking your if statement. If you want the compiler to ignore the if statement as well, you can use a [preprocessor directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) to enclose the whole block like so:

```
#if DEBUG
if (state != "Ok")
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Error occured: {state}, {moreInfo}");
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

The C# compiler is required by the language spec to remove the `Debug` call *and* the evaluation of its arguments.

If the .NET JIT was a sophisticated JIT it would determine that the string method call is not side-effecting and can be deleted. The .NET JIT is not very sophisticated so there's actually a chance it still calls that method. Let's find out.

Compile the program in Release mode, decompile it and run it as x64 on 4.6.2 without the Debugger suppressing optimizations.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var state = GetState();
        if (state != "Ok")
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(state);
        }
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    static string GetState()
    {
        return "x";
    }
```

The C# compiler left the string inequality call intact:

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure whether the spec permits optimizing this out because this might be a side-effecting method. Not sure what the compiler is allowed to assume about it.

Our fantastic JIT also did not remove the call:

[image]

(1) is the `GetState()` and (2) is `string.!=`.

---

Use `Debug.WriteLineIf` because:

> 17.4.2.1 Conditional methods
>   A method decorated with the Conditional attribute is a conditional method. The Conditional attribute indicates a condition by testing a conditional compilation symbol. Calls to a conditional method are either included or omitted depending on whether this symbol is defined at the point of the call. If the symbol is defined, the call is included; otherwise, the call (including evaluation of the receiver and parameters of the call) is omitted.

Comment: Could you reference where in the spec it points out `Debug.X` calls have to be removed?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I added that.